# How to find WSDL file in dynamic webservice project?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I generated dynamic webservice. After creating a class, I generated server side of this project with axis2 and tomcat6. I can't seem to find WSDL file in the project. When I run it on the server, I can go to available service list and I am able to find wsdl file located at http://localhost:8080/Projektuks/services/AddOperator?wsdl, but where is the actual .wsdl file?

I know this question might sound confusing. I can't think of any better explanation. I created a server side of webservice and I want to find generated .wsdl file but I am not able to.

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994541/does-axis-2-automatically-create-and-save-wsdl-file

Answer (score 1):

`wsdl` file you are talking about is generated on the fly. If you want to save it on the local machine you case save it as you would save any other file. See [this resource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs81/doc/en/core/index.html) to know more.